# Prevent WindowManager overlay to make System Navigation Bar sticky at the bottom when opening other fullscreen apps

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an app that when the user clicks a button, it uses WindowManager to show an overlay button on the top left of the screen, it will then minimize the app when the overlay is shown.
Now the user can open other apps while the overlay will stay on the screen's top left.
For normal apps are fine, but if the user opens an app that has to be fullscreen, instead of being fullscreen, the system navigation bar doesn't hide.

Is there any flag I can use or any other solution?

Below is my simplified code for the WindowManager overlay:

```
mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
             )

mWindowManager!!.addView(buttonView, params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `or FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` fixed this problem,
resulting code:

```
mWindowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                    (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or 
                     FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE),
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
             )

mWindowManager!!.addView(buttonView, params)
```